# Can we create an Azure Service Bus (to debug Workflow & Remote Event Receivers) inside Azure VM

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azureservicebus

I am developing some Provider Hosted add-ins for my SharePoint online tenant, and the Provider Hosted add-ins contain WCFs to implement Remote Event Receivers. Now I know that inside Azure subscription account, i can create a new Service Bus, to use it inside my visual studio projects, for debugging and testing my remote event receivers and workflows. For example inside my Azure web portal i have created this service bus:-

[image]

then inside the visual studio's Provider Hosted add-ins Project i entered the service bus information, as follow:-

[image]

This allowed me to debug and test my Remote Event Receivers code (actually i did not find any other way to debug my Remote Event Receivers, rather than specifying an Azure Service Bus). now my question is, if we chose to have an Azure Virtual Machine, instated of Azure subscription. will we still be able to create an Azure  service bus or similar functionality inside IIS? or this option is only provided as part of Azure subscription account?

If the answer, is No (i can not create a service bus inside Azure VM), then is there a way i can debug and test my Remote Event Receivers code, without using Azure service BUS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Azure Service Bus is a hostess on azure service. You can't "create" or "emulate" it on premises or VM.

> if we chose to have an Azure Virtual Machine, instated of Azure subscription. will we still be able to create an Azure service bus inside IIS? or this option is only provided as part of Azure subscription?

Through Azure subscription you get access to services and they're resources. Such as VMs and Azure Service Bus. To use a VM you don't have to use Azure subscription as you could soon one on your machine if you'd like. But you can't run your own Service Bus. IIS or not. For that you'll need to have an acute subscription and create a namespace under Service Bus.

> If the answer, is No (i can not create a service bus inside Azure VM), then is there a way i can debug and test my Remote Event Receiver, without using Azure service BUS??

As mentioned above, you could use a namespace for testing purposes from a VM as long as that VM has access to the internet.

Comment: thanks for your reply. now the Azure VM have access to the Internet, as i will be hosting some sharepoint apps to be used inside our sharepoint online sites, so yes the VM will have access to the internet.  If i get your point correctly, then if i have Azure VM exposed to the internet, then i can create a similar functionality to what Azure subscription provide in respect to Azure Service Bus ? so i can test and debug my remote event receiver and workflows? second point, can you provide some links on how i can create a service-bus like functionality inside Azure VM??

Comment: If VM has access to the Internet and ASB, then yes, you can run ASB-related code. As for the 2nd question on _service-bus like functionality inside Azure VM_ I'm not entirely following your though. What do you mean "service bus like functionality"? Your SB related code is that functionality. If you need various ASB samples, there's plenty of those either in the [samples repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples) or the [documentation site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/). In case you refer to something else, details would be needed.

Comment: now i think i did not explain my problem well. now when i created a new sharepoint Addin using VS 2015, there is an option under "Project>>Properties>>SharePoint tab>>Enable debugging via Microsoft Azure Service Bub". then under this option i can add the connection string for my ASB. this will allow me to test and debug my add in code. now in my case i do not have ASB, as our customer does not have Azure subscription, But we are using Azure VM exposed o the internet... so the question was how i can test and debug my addin code without having ASB??

Comment: or if i want to test/debug my addin code, then i need to have ASB. otherwise i can not test/debug my adddin code... So my question was if i can create a ASB inside my Azure VM ? OR the other option if i can debug my addin code without the need to use ASB.. hope this claify my question. thanks

Comment: You'll need your ASB code. Unless it's abstracted and can be replaced, which I doubt. Keep in mind, _where_ you run doesn't matter. If you have code relying on ASB client/bits, you will exercise it. Hope that clarifies it a bit more for you.

Comment: can you please advice what do you exacly mean by `If you have code relying on ASB client/bits, you will exercise it.`??

Comment: Code that uses ASB client.

Comment: ok so let say inside my Azure VM i developed my own Service Bus which is exposed to the internet,, then where inside my Visual Studio i need to provide the connection string for my Service Bus? as seems inside Visual Studio's Project  properties the option is explicitly for MS Azure Service bus (as shown in the 2nd picture inside my original question). is this correct ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163839/discussion-between-sean-feldman-and-john-g).